# Add page number and author name in the footer

Tags: header-footer

I have the following case:

```
\usepackage{lipsum}%% a garbage package you don't need except to create examples.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{My Name}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\lipsum[1-20]
```

How do I change the footes so that the page is numbered automatically in there also?

Comment: `\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}` or `\fancyfoot[L]{\thepage}`or if it is a twosided document `\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}`. If your first page should also get the name and the page number in footer, remove `\thispagestyle{empty}`

Comment: Alternatively, have a look [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers#How_can_I_have_my_name_and_title_of_my_thesis_in_the_inner_foot.3F).